# Is $8n^3+12n^2-2n-3$ divisible by 5, with $n$ congruent with 1,2,3 mod 5?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I make some test using python and I find that this is the case for $n = 5k +p$ with $k$ an integer and $p =$1,2,or 3.

I was able to prove for $p = 1$ and $p=2$ but not for $p = 3$.

What I'm doing wrong? This is my work:

Let's assume 5 is a divisor of $8n^3+12n^2-2n-3$. Let's prove it for $n + 1.$
We have $8(n+1)^3+12(n+1)^2-2(n+1)-3=8(n^3+3 n^2+3n+1)+12(n^2+2n+1)-2(n+1)-3=(8n^3+12n^2-2-3)+24n^2+48n+18$

For induction we have $8n^3+12n^2-2n-3$, we need only that $5$ divide $24n^2+48n+18$

Since  $n = 5k + p$, $k$ an integer and $p$ with values $1$,$2$ or $3$.
We need to see that $5$ divide $24n^2+48n+18= 24$ with $(5k+p)^2+48(5k+p)+18$,

Using congruence we have $(5k+p)^2$ is congruent with $p^2$ mod 5 and $5k + p$ with $p$ modulo 5.
$f(p)= 24p^2+48p+18$ is divisible with 5 para $p = 1, p = 2$.
So $f(1) = 90$ is divisible for 5 , $f(2)= 210$ and also divisible for 5.
But $f(3)$ is not divisible for 5.

Comment: Is the question asking for all $n$? If yes, then the statement is false. Just take $n=5s$, then all the terms except the constant terms are divisible by $5$. So the entire expression is NOT divisible by $5$.

Comment: No i was asking for $n$ congruent with 1,2,3 mod 5, I edit my question thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative solution. Note that 
$$8n^3+12n^2-2n-3=(2n+3)(2n+1)(2n-1)$$
which is divisible by $5$ iff $(2n+3)$ or $(2n+1)$ or $(2n-1)$ is divisible by $5$. Now
$$\begin{align}
&2n+3\equiv 0\leftrightarrow 2n\equiv -3\equiv 2\leftrightarrow n\equiv 1 \pmod{5}\\
&2n+1\equiv 0\leftrightarrow 2n\equiv -1\equiv 4\leftrightarrow n\equiv 2 \pmod{5}\\
&2n-1\equiv 0\leftrightarrow 2n\equiv 1\equiv 6\leftrightarrow n\equiv 3 \pmod{5}\end{align}$$
Hence $8n^3+12n^2-2n-3$ is divisible by $5$ iff $n\equiv 1,2,3$ modulo $5$.

Answer (score 5):

**OP changed the question:**

So, another solution:

$$8n^3+12n^2-2n-3 \equiv_5 3n^2 + 2n^2 -2 n - 3 \stackrel{n \equiv_5 k}{\equiv_5} 3k^3 + 2k^2 - 2k -3$$

Now:

- $k = 1$: $3+2-2-3 \equiv_5 0$
- $k = 2$: $3\cdot 8 +2\cdot 4 -2\cdot2 -3 \equiv_5 -1 -2-4-3 \equiv_5 0$
- $k = 3$: $3\cdot 27 +2\cdot 9 -2\cdot3 -3 \equiv_5 6 +3-6-3 \equiv_5 0$

.......

Comment: $n=0$ also works.

Comment: I know maybe i ask badly my question, It don't work for $n$ congruent with 4 or 5 mod 5. But is valid for $n$ congruent with 3 mod 5?

Comment: @TommydoNascimiento : I have adjusted my answer to your adjusted question.